# Not getting the desired output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv6bI.png)I want to reverse a number. If 92 is typed the result should be 29. The code is given below

```
def intreverse(n) :
    a=str(n)
    b=a[::-1]
    c=int(b)
    print (c)
```

But i am getting the result as actual output as

- 29/n
- none/n
  Why?

Comment: Are you forgetting to return the reversed value? Python functions return `None` by default if no other value is specified.

Comment: Please stop fixing the indentation! It's very possible that it's part of OP's problem.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Unlikely, indentation would throw an error

Comment: I see a typo please make sure it is b=a[::-1]

Comment: What is your input `n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The course you use probably wants you to write functions with returns. As your function has no return, you get None in the end. And for the newline character `\n`: As you print your answer, print puts a newline character after what you print. If you delete the print statement and put a return statement instead as suggested, both problems will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting newlines in your text input (possibly two?).  I would fix this with

```
 a=str(n).strip()
```

also, you are printing the result, I think you want to return it.  Since the function does not return anything, `a = intreverse('29')` will assign `None` to `a`.  So you want:

```
def intreverse(n) :
 a=str(n).strip()
 b=a[::-1]
 c=int(b)
 return c
```

Or just for the obligatory one-liner:

```
def intreverse(n):
  return int(str(n).strip()[::-1])
```